# Как сделать проверку аргумента в лямбда выражении?

Tags: c#, .net

Нужно чтоб проверка деления на ноль находилась внутри лямбда виражения !

`double Div(double a, double b) => a / b;`

Comment: Проще нормальный метод сделать. Код без выкрутасов читается и понимается лучше.

Comment: Я знаю, но задание сделать именно так

Comment: сделать проверку это одно, а чего получить-то в итоге надо? эксепшн бросить? double, вроде, на на 0 делит нормально (Infinity в итоге будет)

Comment: Что подразумевается под проверкой?

Comment: У вас не лямбда-выражение в вопросе. _Ваш К. О._

Comment: Это называется "Метод, сжатый до выражения" (expression-bodied method)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

К примеру, можно сделать с помощью тернарного оператора, вот так:

```
double Div(double a, double b) => b != 0 ?  a / b : 0;
```

Если у Вас второй параметр (**b**) ноль - вернет ноль. Возвращаемый ноль - всего лишь пример. Оператор `?:` - это тернарный оператор. Почитать можно тут: [Оператор ?: (справочник по C#)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ty67wk28.aspx)

Comment: Это, как минимум, странно возвращать ноль если равен нулю делитель, хотя что хочет ТС для нас так и остается загадкой...

Comment: @Андрей чтобы он не хотел ответ его устроил :D